# Problems with installing valgrind

Tags: installation, downloads

I am really new with Ubuntu, and I am trying install the program with [this](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html) guide. 
But I can't get it to work, and I don't understand what is going on.
I was wondering if somebody could ether tell me how to get it to work or tell what the commands mean.

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem? (edit your original post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't do that. Those instructions are showing you how to compile and install the software manually yourself. In Ubuntu you mostly install software from the *package repositories*.

Open "Software Center" from the dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top of the bar on the left) and search for `valgrind` in there. You'll then be able to install it and, after that's done, to use it.

Comment: Okay, I now see I already had the program installed, I just could not find it in the Dash.
Now I just have to figure out how to use the program :)

Comment: It's generally a program that you use from the terminal. Any detailed usage instructions are probably out of scope for this question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install valgrind`
is what you probably want to do. You chose the hard way not really recommendable for a beginner.

Even easier way is to use the Software Center.

Comment: I tried that, even before I asked the question, and it must have worked, because I can see in the Software Center that I have the program now. I just didn’t know i had it, because when I searched for "Valgrind" in the Dash nothing came up.